# Qt: Showing a list of Users/Clients and when clicked, showing profile

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

in my Qt project, I have a list of Clients. I have to show their name and workplace. Proposed ui looks something like this:

[image: Client table]

Facts:

1. Number of client is variable, so the number of dotted rectangular box in the image is not fixed
2. `stylesheet` of `Name` and `Some info` is different
3. When clicked on the box (a cell in the table), we have to show something like user/client profile for that client.

What we tried:

We tried using tablewidget, but can't handle the function of showing profile based on click on table cell.

We need suggestion how we can implement that.

Comment: You can simply handle the `QTableWidget::itemClicked()` signal and show the profile from the slot it connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using tablewidget is the best idea here (But it could be, depending on your needs and if you pay attention to future evolution).

I think a good solution could be to create a custom widget `MyCell` which would be a cell (Pretty sure you guess it thanks to the name ;) !)

In this MyCell class you can add your information (probably QLineEdit ? No really matter in our example).

Then you have to implement `QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` function, and do what you want in it (Open a new Dialog in your case).

You can have a class `MyTable` with N `MyCell` put in a QGridLayout.